# Possible to group data in resource with automapper?

Tags: c#, automapper

Is it possible to group data in resource with automapper?

For example:

```
public class Order
{
    public Guid ID{ get; set; }

    public ICollection<OrderLine> OrderLines { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class OrderLine
{

    public Guid OrderID { get; set; }
    public Order Order { get; set; }
    public Guid ProductID { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set }
}
```

```
public class Product
{

    public Guid ID{ get; set; }

    public ICollection<OrderLine> OrderLines { get; set; }
}
```

```
 public class OrderResource
    {
        public Guid ID { get; set; }

        public ICollection<YearResource> Years { get; set; }

        public OrderResource()
        {
            Years = new Collection<YearResource>();
        }
    }
```

```
public class YearResource
{
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Guid> ProductIds { get; set; }
}
```

I want the productIds grouped based on the year for example this output:

```
{
    id: "random-id-tst",
    years: [
        {
            year: 1,
            productIds: ['guid-id-1', 'guid-id-2'],
        },
    ]
}
```

I am struggling to get it working with grouping based on Years. So right now I get this:

```
{
    id: "random-id-tst",
    years: [
        {
            year: 1,
            productIds: ['guid-id-1'],
        },
        {
            year: 1,
            productIds: ['guid-id-2'],
        },
    ]
}
```

I tried to use groupBy but I think it's not supported by automapper and can'get it to work.

```
cfg.CreateMap<Order, OrderResource>().ForMember(dest => dest.Years, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.OrderLines.Select(ol => ol.Product).ToList()))

// tried grouping on OrderLines but that's not working
cfg.CreateMap<Product, YearResource>().ForMember(dest => dest.Year, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.OrderLines.Select(e => e.Year).First()));
```

Comment: No, you have to group using LINQ and integrate that with AM.

Comment: You need to use GroupBy of LINQ

Comment: Before I map to my resource?

Comment: In the MapFrom area @user3190617

Answer (score 1):

You need to use GroupBy of LINQ. Here is an example about the usage of GroupBy, this example provides to group Cars according to their names,

```
List<Car> cars = new List<Car>();
cars.Add(new Car() { Name = "Renault", Price = 250 });
cars.Add(new Car() { Name = "BMW", Price = 700 });
cars.Add(new Car() { Name = "Renault", Price = 150 });
cars.Add(new Car() { Name = "Renault", Price = 250 });
cars.Add(new Car() { Name = "Renault", Price = 100 });

List<Car> result = cars.GroupBy(x => x.Name).Select(x => new Car() { Name = x.Key, Price = x.Sum(y=>y.Price) }).ToList();

//to print output
result.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(string.Concat("Name: ", x.Name, " Total Price: ", x.Price)));
Console.ReadKey();
```

And Car model,

```
public class Car {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I tried to use GroupBy but that doesn’t work with automapper, seems like I have to group when accesing the db.

Comment: But there is no GroupBy in the code you have shared @user3190617

Comment: I commented `// tried grouping on OrderLines but that's not working`

Comment: Can you share the code which is not working and please explain how it doesn't work. I mean, does it throw an exception or does it group the items in a wrong way @user3190617